# Calling library functions from different language

Tags: java, c, function, system, libraries

As we know libraries are precompiled programs. So, can libraries of a language be used by other languages? If so, how can I call a C library function from Java?

Comment: Probably looking for JNI. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Comment: Look e.g. for the _Java Native Interface (JNI)_. In most languages, you can call C functions, but often not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

Can one language call into a library written in another?  Sometimes, depends on the languages and libraries.

For C and Java, check out the Java Native Interface:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface